# OneToMany JPA annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Its a simple question and wont take too much time.

Suppose this:

```
Class A{ ... }

Class B{
  @OneToMany
  private A a;
}
```

It means that one B can have many A or many A can have one B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means B can have many A, and your `private A a` should be represented by some sort of `Collection`, and it's `@OneToMany` decoration should include a `mappedBy` attribute pointing to the Many side's corresponding field/property

```
public class B {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b");
    private Collection<A> as;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "B_ID")
    private Long id;
}

public class A {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID");
    private B b;
}
```

Comment: As @Elvermg noted, this _is_ an example of bi-driectional relationship, where both entities know about each other, but there are also unidirectional replationships where one knows about the other, but not vice versa. His answer shows that example. +1 to him for noting that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by peeskillet is right, but it uses an example of bidirectional relationship. This is, class A knows about class B, and class B knows about class A.
You can use this in a non bidirectional relationship:

```
public class B
{
     @OneToMany
     private Collection<A> a;
}


public class A{}
```

Class B knows about class A, but class A doesn't knows about class B.

Hope this help too. :)